# How to load only specific objects from DB in wordpress by using meta_query with NOT LIKE compare?

Tags: wordpress

I have followed snippets of code that fetch `exercise` objects from database:

```
<?php 
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'excersize' ),
    'posts_per_page'=>500,
    "orderby"=>"menu_order date"
 );

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
$cources = $the_query->get_posts();

foreach($cources as $cource)
{  
 $cource->thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($cource->ID);
 $cource->promo = get_post_meta($cource->ID, 'excersize', TRUE);
 $cource->link = get_permalink($cource->ID);
}
?>
```

After  I run over all `$cources` and do some stuff:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var courcesJ = <?php echo json_encode($cources);?>;
jQuery(function($) {

for(var i  = 0 ; i< courcesJ.length ; i++) 
{       
 // .... do something   
}
});
</script>
```

My problem is that I have a lot of `excersizes`, about **500** for that reason page loads slowly, 
 actually I need to show only objects that don't contain `-` character in `post_title`. All other 495 don't have `-` and I don't need them at all.

**How can I load only specific `excersizes` where `post_title` dont contain `-` charecter from DB to increase performance?**

*this is example of element in `courcesJ` array*:

[image]

**[Edit]**

I tried to use meta_query:

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'post_title', 
                'value' => '%-%', 
                'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
            )
        ),
    'post_type' => array( 'excersize'),
    'posts_per_page'=>500,
    "orderby"=>"menu_order date"
);
```

Still doesn't work

Thank you for help,

Answer (score 1):

`meta_query` works on fields in the `wp_postmeta` table; post title is stored in the `wp_posts` table, so `meta_query` won't help you here.

Take a look at [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18703/wp-query-with-post-title-like-something) on the WordPress stackexchange; the answers seem to do what you're after by using the `posts_where` filter.